# Simpleform Append only works for some input types

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I have an input wrapper component:

```
module InputGroup
    def prepend(wrapper_options = nil)
      span_tag = content_tag(:span, options[:prepend], class: "input-group-text")
      template.content_tag(:div, span_tag, class: "input-group-prepend")
    end

    def append(wrapper_options = nil)
      span_tag = content_tag(:span, options[:append], class: "input-group-text")
      template.content_tag(:div, span_tag, class: "input-group-append")
    end
  end
```

Which I can use like this successfully:

<%= f.input :amount, prepend: '$' %>

However, when used with a date field it does not work, no symbol prepended:

<%= f.input :start_on, as: :date, html5: true, prepend: "£" %>

How can I adjust my InputGroup component to work for html5 date fields?

Comment: Why would you want to prepend a date with `£`?

Comment: lol, i dont, just an example string.